# How extract all sql CrystalClear

Tags: java, sql, oracle

It's my first time with `CrystalClear` but I have to extract all sql query. I have this report ( the db works). The problem is I want have all sql that I can use to modify.

I do "show sql" but it  is not give me all sql ,

If I open the reporst.xml, it add something params that I cannot see.

Anyone can help

Comment: Sometimes you can ask the DBA to give a report of the queries ran in the last 60 minutes. You can use that to see what's going on under the hood.